# Swift Generic func gen<T>(arg: T) where T : Optional<U>, U : Equatable

Tags: swift, generics

How do I express a Swift generic function which constraints that `T` be an `Optional<Equatable>`?

I've tried things like the following, with the resulting errors.

`func gen<T>(arg: T) where T : Optional<Equatable>`

- Type 'T' constrained to non-protocol type 'Optional'

`func gen<T>(arg: T) where T : OptionalProtocol<Equatable>`

- Cannot specialize non-generic type 'OptionalProtocol'

`func gen<T, U>(arg: T) where T : Optional<U>, U : Equatable`

- Type 'T' constrained to non-protocol type 'Optional'
- Generic parameter 'U' is not used in function signature

Thanks.

### Edit

I was doing something like

```
if let a = arg, let b = argb
    return a==b
```

It turns out that my error wasn't in the templating at all, it was just that the object I was working with wasn't, in fact, Equatable. I guess I assumed Swift would generate == for a struct with elements that are all themselves =='able, but it does not. Next time I'll know what the error `Expression type 'Bool' is ambiguous without more context` is suggesting.

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm missing something but can you use 'arg: T?' in your first example?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should work:

```
func gen<T>(arg: T?) where T : Equatable { /*...*/ }
```

Which is equivalent to this:

```
func gen<T>(arg: Optional<T>) where T : Equatable { /*...*/ }
```

Remember,

1. Generics are for the variable part of your type requirements. That you require `Optional` is constant; it's the optional-*what* part that's variable. So put the optionality in the actual func declaration, and leave the optional-*what* for generics.
2. The colon in type parameters expresses a subtype relationship. A type `T` can't be a subtype of `Optional<Something>` because `Optional` is an enum — only classes and protocols can have subtypes (subclasses and conforming types respectively). Likewise, generics aren't covariant, so `Optional<Foo>` where `Foo` adopts `Equatable` isn't a subtype of `Optional<T: Equatable>`.

Answer (score 1):

```
func gen<T>(arg: T?) where T : Equatable {

    if let arg = arg {
        print("arg is '\(arg)', Equatable")
    } else {
        print("arg is nil")
    }
}
```

### Example Use

```
let testValue1: Int? = 1
gen(arg: testValue1)

let testValue2: String? = "One"
gen(arg: testValue2)

let testValue3: String? = nil
gen(arg: testValue3)
```

### Console Output

```
arg is '1', Equatable

arg is 'One', Equatable

arg is nil
```